# what does the npm peer install errors mean?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I'm new to node and trying to build a project that doesn't have much instructions with it.  So I've been trying various suggestions but haven't made much progress.

What does the following npm build error mean?

> > ref@1.3.5 install /Users/matt/src/work/indy-sdk/vcx/wrappers/node/node_modules/ref
> >     node-gyp rebuild
>
> gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed:
>   /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python -c import sys; print
>   "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3]; gyp ERR! stack   File "",
>   line 1 gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" %
>   sys.version_info[:3]; gyp ERR! stack                                ^
>   gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax gyp ERR! stack gyp ERR!
>   stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:297:12) gyp
>   ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13) gyp ERR! stack 
>   at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:395:11) gyp ERR!
>   stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:197:13) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Pipe._handle.close (net.js:611:12) gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0 gyp
>   ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.9.0/bin/node"
>   "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd
>   /Users/matt/src/work/indy-sdk/vcx/wrappers/node/node_modules/ref gyp
>   ERR! node -v v11.9.0 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0 gyp ERR! not ok npm
>   WARN babel-loader@6.2.4 requires a peer of webpack@1 || ^2.1.0-beta
>   but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

I'm new to node and trying to build a project that doesn't any build instructions with it.   I've already run suggestions found on slack:

- `npm i`
- `npm install`
- `npm install webpack --save-dev`
- `npm audit fix`

None of these have progressed my progress on solving the problem.

It looks like I am suppose to manually install some dependencies but I am unsure what that involves.....?

Thnx

Comment: It's trying to execute python script and get syntax error. Check your python version, is it 3.6?

Comment: once I followed the answer below, I no longer get build errors.  I double checked, just to make sure there are not other potential problems.   I am using python version 3.7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating npm:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Sometimes npm is the root cause, not the packages.

Edit: After you update npm, if nothing changes reinstall the packages.